# Login form doesn't render for custom Django login page

Tags: python, html, django

Django newbie here trying to create a custom login form, view and template. My problem is that the logic in my view is causing the form to not be displayed, and instead, the error message from the else statement always shows up. I'm sure I'm missing something, I just have no idea what it is. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have been working from the Django docs and this tutorial: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14.html  Thank you!

**UPDATE:** User @AKS pointed out that I wasn't handling the POST/GET logic properly, so I accepted this as the answer. Once I adjusted my code, the form still wouldn't display, so I discovered some errors in the HTML file and fixed them. The corrected code is shown at the bottom of this post.

**-- views.py --**

```
# Django imports
from django import forms
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.utils import timezone

# Local Django imports
from .models import *
from .forms import *


def login(request, method='POST'):
    '''Shows a login form and a registration link.'''

    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("client/items")

    else:
        return HttpResponse("Invalid login. Please try again.")

    return render(request, "registration/login.html", {'next':'/client/items'})
```

**-- registration/login.html --**

```
{% extends "registration/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action='/login'>{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**-- settings.py --**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'clients'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**-- app/urls.py --**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^register$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^client/items$', views.client_items, name='client_items'),
    url(r'^client/new_item$', views.new_item, name='new_item'),
    url(r'^client/edit_item$', views.edit_item, name='edit_item'),
    url(r'^client/item_detail$', views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
]
```

**-- Corrected registration/login.html --**

```
{% extends "registration/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username"><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Nope, not logged in!

Comment: :) Did that fix it?

Comment: show us your `urls.py` file

Comment: @Pavan thanks, I just added the urls.py file to the end of my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the execution never reaches the last `return` statement because it is either satisfying `if` condition, else it returns the `Invalid Login` response.

```
if user is not None and user.is_active:
    auth.login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("client/items")

else:
    return HttpResponse("Invalid login. Please try again.")

return render(request, "registration/login.html", {'next':'/client/items'})
```

It seems you need to process the form in `POST` request and return the login form in case of `GET` request:

```
def login(request, method='POST'):
    '''Shows a login form and a registration link.'''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("client/items")

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login. Please try again.")

    # if not POST then return login form    
    return render(request, "registration/login.html", {'next':'/client/items'})
```

Comment: Many thanks, AKS! You're absolutely right, I forgot to make the distinction in the logic between POST/GET. Once I made these changes, the template (which should have displayed the form) still was not displaying properly, so I deduced that it must be the HTML file that was causing this. Sure enough, the HMTL example I mirrored was using templating but I wasn't passing a form into the template. I just re-wrote the HTML and the login form now shows up. (I'm getting an unrelated error, which I'm puzzling out now.) I will post the revised HTML code in my post. Thanks again!